# Always launch the main activity

Tags: android

My application has 4 activities. If the user clicks the home button, the next time the application is launched, I want it to start on the main activity not the last activity it was on. If the phone's display turns off, as long as the application hasn't been closed, I want it to resume where it left off. What is the proper way to go about this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just set `clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` in your manifest main activity declaration.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear

Comment: I've done that but it doesn't appear to do anything. If I set finishOnTaskLaunch for all activities except main, it does what I want but I'm not sure that's the best way.

Comment: This option seems buggy, try to set `android:finishOnTaskLaunch ="true"` on all other activities except the main one. Keep the `clearTaskOnLaunch="true"`

Comment: One thing to note certainly with the finishOnTaskLaunch property is that it won't work if you build the app to the device directly from eclipse. You have to install the apk manually for it to actually take effect. Nightmare for debugging

Comment: @Dean it works for me. Maybe it was a bug that was fixed in the later SDK.

Comment: Only works if I launch the other activity with: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Comment: ```clearTaskOnLaunch="true"``` worked fine for me on API 27.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't answer all parts of your question, but it sounds as though you'd benifit from looking at these attributes in the manifest; [launchmode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode), [finishOnTaskLaunch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#finish), [clearTaskOnLaunch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is a problem of affinity and recent list. Here is how i solved it.

android:taskAffinity="com.packageName.Excluded"
android:excludeFromRecents="true"

so all tasks with the same affinity will not be listed in recent list.
Note : excludeFromRecents will exclude all the tasks with same affinity in one go, so if you don't set the affinity of the activity, your application will be excluded from recent list(app activities use same affinity by default if not set)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    keeper += 1;
    if (keeper == 2){
        Intent iii = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SplashActivity.class);
        startActivity(iii);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should implement all theses cases on the onPause and onResume methods of your Activity.

You should learn the Activity lifecycle
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html