# Re-launch app on application launcher icon tap

Tags: android, icons, launcher, tap, relaunch

According to Android behavior when user takes an app to background by pressing home button, on launcher icon tap the app will resume from where it went to background. I want a different behavior in my app, i want to relaunch the launcher activity whenever user taps on the launcher icon, no matter the app is in background or not.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want this behaviour, maybe you should try to handle the relaunch.

Comment: Override the `onResume()` method in your activities, to close all the running activities and launch the launcher activity.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5540250/3697191

Answer (score 1):

just set this in your launcher activity

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```